# How to retrieve and change data from json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am having difficulties accessing my json file from my javascript file. I would like to change the data in the status section of my json file once a submit button is clicked on the webpage. I am aware that I would use ajax to achieve this goal, but I do not know how to access the json file.

This is the db.json file

```
{
{
  "assets": [
    {
      
      "id": "0946",
      "manufacturer": "SONY",
    },
    {
      "id": "0949",
      "manufacturer": "AUDIOTECNIA"
      
    }
],
  "transfers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": "in-progress"
    }
               ]
}
```

This is my Javascript file

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        parsedData = JSON.parse(db.json);
        console.log(parsedData[0].id)


    //Changing Status 

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "PATCH",
        url: `http://localhost:3000/transfers/`
        
        
    });
```

I've tried using parseData because I read that is how to retrieve the object, from the json file, but I do not believe I am writing it correctly. What documentation or steps would one recommend for solving this issue?

Comment: what is the ```console.log``` output?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: db is not defined. I think im not referencing the file name correctly @OvidijusParsiunas

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; changing the *file* requires re-writing the file in the server code (whatever is serving `localhost:3000`). Updating the data *locally* (in the client, e.g., the browser) is object manipulation. Ultimately it's not clear what's meant by "access the JSON file".

Comment: Where is the ```db.json``` file stored? If you are using webpack, you can import it via the ```import``` syntax. Or alternatively you can import it into your html like so:
```<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="db.json"></script> ``` Your code above should then work :)

Comment: its object manipulation! this is a local change im trying to work on @DaveNewton how would I go about posting a local change to my json file?

Answer (score 0):

You missed assets

```
console.log(parsedData.assets[0].id)
```

I am assuming this string AND that the file is on a web server since you cannot ajax a file from harddisk

```
json: "{\"assets\": [{\"id\": \"0946\",\"manufacturer\": \"SONY\"}, {\"id\": \"0949\", \"manufacturer\": \"AUDIOTECNIA\"}],\"transfers\": [{\"id\": 1,\"status\": \"in-progress\"}]}"}
```

```js
const db = {
    json: "{\"assets\": [{\"id\": \"0946\",\"manufacturer\": \"SONY\"}, {\"id\": \"0949\", \"manufacturer\": \"AUDIOTECNIA\"}],\"transfers\": [{\"id\": 1,\"status\": \"in-progress\"}]}"}

    parsedData = JSON.parse(db.json);
    console.log(parsedData.assets[0].id)
```